# How to load an specific activity(Intent) on Listview(item)Click?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

```
 package com.example.app;

 import com.example.app.adaptor.*;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ListView;


 public class ListviewExample extends ListActivity {

static final String[] ASDFGH = new String[] { "ABC", "PQR",
        "XYZ", "RAA","AA" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setListAdapter(new etcArray(this, main_activity ));

}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    // get selected items
    String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            if(selectedValue.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC"))
    {
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ABC.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
    else
        if(selectedValue.equalsIgnoreCase("AA"))
        {
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AA.class);         
            startActivity(in);
        }

   }
```

In the above program ..using normal condition like if string.equalsIgnorecase("AA")
 we can launch the intent on that specific click !! is there any method to launch an activity in any listview Item Click ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create class array as well So you can point to exact activity easily ...

```
static final Class[] classArray = new Class[] { ABC.class,PQR.class,XYZ.class,RAA.class,AA.class };
static final String[] ASDFGH = new String[] { "ABC", "PQR",
"XYZ", "RAA","AA" };

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
Intent intent=newIntent(getApplicationContext(),classArray[position]);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help..Type mismatch error:you cannot convert String[] to Class[]

Comment: please check update now.. actually it's Class object. By mistake i wrote String..

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code :

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Class<?> nextClass = null;
    // get selected items
    String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    if(selectedValue.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC"))
        nextClass = ABC.class;
    else if(selectedValue.equalsIgnoreCase("AA"))
        nextClass = AA.class;
    if(nextClass != null)
        startActivity(new Intent(context, nextClass));

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run following code.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {


    // get selected items

    if(position == 0)
    {
        Intent intent=newIntent(this, Class1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if(poition == 1)
    {
         Intent intent=newIntent(this, Class2.class);
         startActivity(intent);
    } else if(poition == 1)
        Intent intent=newIntent(this, Class3.class);
         startActivity(intent);

}
```